# Inheriting options with Boost.ProgramOptions

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

Is there a good way to chain inherit program options from another `options_description` object in boost?  For example

```
auto general_options = po::options_description{};
general_options.add_options()
   ("flag", "Information for --flag");

auto specific_options_one = po::options_description{};
specific_options.add_options(general_options)
    ("specific_flag_one", "Information for specific flag");

auto specific_options_two = po::options_description{};
specific_options_two.add_options(general_options)
    ("specific_flag_two", "Information for specific flag");
```

i.e. get the `specific_options` options instance to use another instance's options along with its own

Such a thing would enable me to specify the `--flag` option for both the `specific_options_one` and the `specific_options_two` instances.  For example

```
./a.out --flag --specific_flag_one
./a.out --flag --specific_flag_two
```

would both be valid since `--flag` is inherited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Multiple Sources Example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#idp523416032) from the doc you can see that it is possible to add an `option_description` to another one, which means you could do something like that:

```
auto general_options = po::options_description{};
general_options.add_options()
   ("flag", "Information for --flag");

auto specific_options_one = po::options_description{};
specific_options.add(general_options).add_options(general_options)
    ("specific_flag_one", "Information for specific flag");

auto specific_options_two = po::options_description{};
specific_options_two.add(general_options).add_options(general_options)
    ("specific_flag_two", "Information for specific flag");
```

Then both `specific_options_one` and `specific_options_two` will contain the flags from `general_options`

Comment: Edited the answer to make it fit perfectly! Thanks

Comment: @Curious Fair enough :)